# Two divs share the same linear gradient background

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

I have two child divs and I want them to have the same linear gradient background, the top div is dynamic and it moves left, right and center, so I want to have the same background as bottom div.

[image]

```
#pool-container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;


#side-step {
  background: linear-gradient( 120deg, rgba(248, 201, 129, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 76, 145, 1) 100%);
}
#main-pool {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient( 120deg, rgba(248, 201, 129, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 76, 145, 1) 100%);
}


<div id="pool-container">
    <div id="side-step"></div>
    <div id="main-pool"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried simply adding the gradient to #pool-container?

Comment: yes but then it takes whole space, i do not need it where i have white space near #side-step

Comment: your code does not create the picture you added

Comment: @ZarghamKhan then make a white square (or from your screenshot it would be a yellow square) to go over top that area that shouldn't have a gradient background

Comment: yes its a good workaround, but side-step container is dynamic when it comes to center i will have to add two containers then.

Comment: Can you share what it would look like when the top div moves to the center or the start?

Comment: I would suggest using JavaScript to calculate the starting and ending colors of the gradient based on the position, but your slanted angle of 120 degrees makes this very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trick using pseudo element. The idea is to make both pseudo element relative to the main container (not to each element) and there you apply the gradient. Then we use `clip-path` to clip the pseudo element so they only show inside their element:

```css
#pool-container {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: green;
  position:relative;
}

#side-step {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  transition:1s all;
}
#pool-container:hover #side-step{
  margin-left:150px;
}
#side-step, 
#main-pool {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
}
#side-step::before, 
#main-pool::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: linear-gradient( 120deg, rgba(248, 201, 129, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 76, 145, 1) 100%);
}

#main-pool {
  width: 100%;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pool-container">
  <div id="side-step"></div>
  <div id="main-pool"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much it works perfectly,  how can i remove small line appearing between two shapes ?

Comment: @ZarghamKhan you see a small line here in the snippet? I don't see it

Comment: @ZarghamKhan in the snippet here? are you enabling the zoom

Comment: oh my zoom was 90%, why did this happen ?

Comment: @ZarghamKhan it's known that zooming create some visual glitch so always check if the zoom is enabled if you get a strange result ;)

Comment: once more question please, I am unable to add border now, probably its because of clippath, how can i do that ?

Comment: @ZarghamKhan hmm, it would be more tricky in this case. Maybe I will need another code. I will think about. By the way you can always ask a new question to have more users thinking about

Comment: alright I will add new question, can i tag you there ? I just joined stack today :)

Comment: @ZarghamKhan no need to tag me, I will see it, I follow all the CSS question ;)

Comment: i have created new question, please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a how you can do it

Is there a better way to do ? honestly i don't know.

```css
#pool-container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #119955;
  padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient( 120deg, rgba(248, 201, 129, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 76, 145, 1) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#excluded-area {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #119955
}

#side-step {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

#main-pool {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pool-container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="excluded-area"></div>
        <div id="side-step"></div>
        <div id="main-pool"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i had a thought to do this way but the side-step container is dynamic when it comes to the center i will have to add two containers  right and left, i hope that there is anybetter solution.